# NTAG 213 password protection

Tags: android, react-native, nfc

If you have a custom app that has the password to authenticate to a NTAG213 chip, how do you stop someone from opening the app source code and getting the password that is saved within the app?
Thanks,
voldomazta

Comment: An answer may depend on your unknown business case. E.g. you can generate the password (and pack) randomly and store it in EncryptedSharedPreferences. Or the user enters a passphrase and password/pack is derived by a cryptographic function like PBKDF2 or or or...

Comment: From memory the RF transmission are not cryptographically secure on the NTAG21x series, so whatever you do to secure the password can be got by listening to the radio transmissions (OK this is a lot more difficult but still possible)

Comment: No I mean if you have thousands of tags and have all the same password and the password is saved in your "custom app" source code to unlock all of them. Is the only way to reverse-engineer this password to listen to the transmission as per @Andrew? Can one not open the app source code and get the password from there?

Comment: If you store the password in your App's Java/Kotlin source then yes it is very easy to extract it from the App (also possible but harder if you store it in a native library in your application). NFC is very difficult to totally secure as there are even "man in the middle" type attacks or using rooted/custom Android phones as well. So the short answer is you cannot totally protect anything NFC, just make it harder to crack.

Comment: Noted. If you put this as an answer I will totally accept it.